# Is Spark executing same partition on same executor?

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Before explaining my real case scenario I ask the question as simple as possible:

If I do repartition 3 times on same dataframe, with same partition key field and same partitions number using HashPartitioner, partition composition will be the same since hashing key is not changed (*key_hash % partitions_number* gives always the same result).

Is spark internally assinging same partition id to same executor or it assigns partitions to random executors?

For example after key hasing, partition 1 will always have same elements if partitions number is not changed even if I do repartition 3 times, but will data be moved around executors or is partition 1 always in charge to executor 1 for example?

**Real case scenario** is:

I have:

```
spark.sql("select key, topic, row_number() over (partition by key,topic order by key) as rn from x").createOrReplaceTempView("y")
//mappartitions operation, producing dataframe z, then ->
spark.sql("select key, collect_list(row_number) from z group by key")
```

In this example, first it's partitioning by (key, topic), then it will repartition by key (to fulfill group by), this can be avoided by doing a *repartition by key* as first operation, this will save one repartition operation since partitioning by key is good for both operations, but since there is a mappartition spark can't know it and so it will trigger a repartition again.

This is inevitable I think, my question is, is still worth to do the repartition as top operation even if spark will execute again same repartition? Will I save data moving around executors or even if partitions will be exactly the same data will be moved in any case?

Here an example of query plan, at line 3 is doing the same hashpartitioning already performed as first operation, this is caused by mappartition usage at line 7

```
 +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(rowkey#817, column_name#815 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS segment_index#839], [rowkey#817], [column_name#815 ASC NULLS FIRST]
                  +- *(5) Sort [rowkey#817 ASC NULLS FIRST, column_name#815 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(rowkey#817, 10), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#647]
                        +- *(4) Project [rowkey#817, topic#808, field1#809, field2#810, field3#811, field4#812, field5#813, column_name#815, struct(trid, cast(value#828.rt_trid as string), dataDt, value#828.rt_data_dt, dataDtUtc, value#828.rt_start_date_utc, eventIdx, cast(value#828.rt_event_idx as int), lastEvent, value#828.rt_last_event, recordType, value#828.rt_record_type, latitude, value#828.geo.rt_latitude, longitude, value#828.geo.rt_longitude, altitude, value#828.geo.rt_altitude, country, value#828.address.rt_country, county, value#828.address.rt_county, state, value#828.address.rt_state, ... 58 more fields) AS json_struct#881]
                           +- *(4) Project [cast(rowkey#807 as string) AS rowkey#817, topic#808, field1#809, field2#810, field3#811, field4#812, field5#813, column_name#815, avrodeserializerexpression(value#816, hbase, (hbase.columns.cq,schema), (hbase.namespace,dev), (hbase.columns.name.value,EnrichedJourney), (hbase.columns.namespace.value,com.vodafone.automotive.wasp.telematics.datamodel.journey), (hbase.columns.cf,0), (hbase.table,SCHEMA_REPOSITORY), true) AS value#828]
                              +- *(4) SerializeFromObject [if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, rowkey), BinaryType) AS rowkey#807, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, topic), StringType), true, false, true) AS topic#808, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, field1), BinaryType) AS field1#809, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 3, field2), BinaryType) AS field2#810, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 4, field3), BinaryType) AS field3#811, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 5, field4), BinaryType) AS field4#812, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 6, field5), BinaryType) AS field5#813, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 8, column_name), StringType), true, false, true) AS column_name#815, if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 9, value), BinaryType) AS value#816]
                                 +- MapPartitions ######.hbase.HBaseReader$$$Lambda$3992/510160290@44b639d3, obj#806: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
                                    +- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(rowkey#787, topic#738.toString, field1#749, field2#751, field3#753, field4#755, field5#757, StructField(rowkey,BinaryType,true), StructField(topic,StringType,true), StructField(field1,BinaryType,true), StructField(field2,BinaryType,true), StructField(field3,BinaryType,true), StructField(field4,BinaryType,true), StructField(field5,BinaryType,true)), obj#805: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
                                       +- *(3) Project [cast(rowkey#737 as binary) AS rowkey#787, topic#738, field1#749, field2#751, field3#753, field4#755, field5#757]
                                          +- *(3) Filter castProcessBooleanUDF(consolidationResult#759)
                                             +- SortAggregate(key=[rowkey#737, topic#738, column_family#739], functions=[max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field1)) value#741 else null), max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field2)) value#741 else null), max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field3)) value#741 else null), max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field4)) value#741 else null), max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field5)) value#741 else null), max(if ((column_name#740 <=> consolidationResult)) value#741 else null)])
                                                +- SortAggregate(key=[rowkey#737, topic#738, column_family#739], functions=[partial_max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field1)) value#741 else null), partial_max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field2)) value#741 else null), partial_max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field3)) value#741 else null), partial_max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field4)) value#741 else null), partial_max(if ((column_name#740 <=> field5)) value#741 else null), partial_max(if ((column_name#740 <=> consolidationResult)) value#741 else null)])
                                                   +- *(2) Sort [rowkey#737 ASC NULLS FIRST, topic#738 ASC NULLS FIRST, column_family#739 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                                      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(rowkey#737, 10), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [id=#630]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some tests with a spark 3 shell of 4 executors,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ hash, lit }
import spark.implicits._
def printPlanAndPartitions(df: DataFrame, name: String): Unit = {
  df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { case (idx, i) =>
    println(s"$name -> partition $idx, values => ${i.toList}")
    i
  }.count()
  sc.parallelize(1 to 4,4).foreachPartition(_ => println("---------------------------------"))
}

val df = sc.parallelize((1 to 20).map(x => x % 4 -> x ), 4).toDF("value", "valuex")
val df2 = df.repartition(4,$"value")
val df2_1 = df2.mapPartitions(r => r)(RowEncoder(df2.schema))
val df3 = df2_1.repartition(4,$"value")
val df3_1 = df3.mapPartitions(r => r)(RowEncoder(df2.schema))
val df4 = df3_1.repartition(4,$"value")
printPlanAndPartitions(df2,"2")
printPlanAndPartitions(df2_1,"2_1")
printPlanAndPartitions(df3,"3")
printPlanAndPartitions(df3_1,"3_1")
printPlanAndPartitions(df4,"4")
sc.parallelize(1 to 4,4).foreachPartition(_ => println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n\n\n"))
```

After each mapPartitions, which does nothing, an hash repartition is triggered df4.explain returns

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(value#1587, 4), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#2579]
+- *(3) SerializeFromObject [validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, value), IntegerType) AS value#1587, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, valuex), IntegerType) AS valuex#1588]
   +- MapPartitions $line218.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$4546/1755336413@56174c86, obj#1586: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
      +- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(value#1581, valuex#1582, StructField(value,IntegerType,false), StructField(valuex,IntegerType,false)), obj#1585: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#1581, 4), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#2573]
            +- *(2) SerializeFromObject [validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, value), IntegerType) AS value#1581, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, valuex), IntegerType) AS valuex#1582]
               +- MapPartitions $line216.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$4545/2107915335@709c4bb7, obj#1580: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
                  +- DeserializeToObject createexternalrow(value#1563, valuex#1564, StructField(value,IntegerType,false), StructField(valuex,IntegerType,false)), obj#1579: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
                     +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                        +- InMemoryTableScan [value#1563, valuex#1564]
                              +- InMemoryRelation [value#1563, valuex#1564], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                                    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#1563, 4), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#2278]
                                       +- *(1) Project [_1#1558 AS value#1563, _2#1559 AS valuex#1564]
                                          +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1 AS _1#1558, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#1559]
                                             +- Scan[obj#1557]
```

Shell is printing inside each executor which partitions is elaborating, from 0 to 3 and contained values, with this version values remains the same per partition id but the executor is running a different partition every time.
Here an example of one executor output

```
2 -> partition 1, values => List()
---------------------------------
2_1 -> partition 3, values => List([3,7], [0,8], [1,9], [3,11], [0,12], [1,13], [3,15], [0,16], [1,17], [3,19], [0,20], [1,1], [3,3], [0,4], [1,5])
---------------------------------
3 -> partition 2, values => List([2,6], [2,10], [2,14], [2,18], [2,2])
---------------------------------
3_1 -> partition 2, values => List([2,6], [2,10], [2,18], [2,14], [2,2])
---------------------------------
4 -> partition 3, values => List([3,7], [0,8], [1,9], [0,16], [1,17], [3,19], [0,20], [3,11], [0,12], [1,13], [3,15], [1,1], [3,3], [0,4], [1,5])
---------------------------------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But if I add a cache after first repartition

```
...
val df2 = df.repartition(4,$"value").cache
...
```

I'm getting mixed results, but it seems to have a certain trend to avoid moving data around, here results from 2 executors

```
2 -> partition 1, values => List()
---------------------------------
2_1 -> partition 1, values => List()
---------------------------------
3 -> partition 1, values => List()
---------------------------------
3_1 -> partition 0, values => List()
---------------------------------
4 -> partition 0, values => List()
---------------------------------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx First executor


2 -> partition 2, values => List([2,18], [2,14], [2,2], [2,6], [2,10])
---------------------------------
2_1 -> partition 2, values => List([2,18], [2,14], [2,2], [2,6], [2,10])
---------------------------------
3 -> partition 2, values => List([2,18], [2,14], [2,2], [2,6], [2,10])
---------------------------------
3_1 -> partition 2, values => List([2,18], [2,14], [2,2], [2,6], [2,10])
---------------------------------
4 -> partition 2, values => List([2,18], [2,14], [2,2], [2,6], [2,10])
---------------------------------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Second executor
```

As you can see it's not moving partition 2 which is populated but sometimes it changes executor for empty partitions, I think it has some mechanism which tries to reduce shuffling at minimum by scheduling a partition where data is stored.

Even with 8 partitions same behaviour is presenting

```
2 -> partition 6, values => List([4,12], [2,18], [4,20], [2,10], [2,2], [4,4])
2 -> partition 0, values => List()
---------------------------------
2_1 -> partition 0, values => List()
2_1 -> partition 6, values => List([4,12], [2,18], [4,20], [2,10], [2,2], [4,4])
---------------------------------
3 -> partition 6, values => List([4,12], [2,18], [4,20], [2,10], [2,2], [4,4])
3 -> partition 5, values => List()
---------------------------------
3_1 -> partition 6, values => List([4,12], [2,18], [4,20], [2,10], [2,2], [4,4])
---------------------------------
4 -> partition 6, values => List([4,12], [2,18], [4,20], [2,10], [2,2], [4,4])
4 -> partition 4, values => List()
```

I also tried to do a cache before first repartition but with that it is moving data around again

```
...
val df = sc.parallelize((1 to 20).map(x => x % 4 -> x ), 4).toDF("value", "valuex").cache
val df2 = df.repartition(4,$"value")
...
```

I hope this analysis was intresting, enjoy